# Microsoft C++ exception: boost::archive::archive_exception at memory location(Parsing Vector through client server Boost Udp)

Tags: c++, memory, serialization, boost, deserialization

[exception: boost::archive::archive_exception at memory location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317403/exception-boostarchivearchive-exception-at-memory-location)

I found this but not useful because he is doing for files and I want to do only for the vector.

Problem:  I did the serialization of the vector on the server side and parsing to the client side and there I'm doing deserialize. so everything is working fine for the 1/2 records.

but If i insert more than 2 records and parse it through vector its giving me this error on the client side where I deserialize the data: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::archive::archive_exception at memory location

this is my code:

Server Side:

serializeData by giving Vector as an Input

```
//I think these headers are enough !!!

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include<boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include<boost/serialization/map.hpp>

template<class input>
void UdpServer::serializeData(input &vector) { // Here i use vector in parameter
    std::ostringstream archive_stream;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream);
    archive << vector;
    sendMessageToClients(archive_stream.str());//sending to client
}
```

The client side where I get the error,

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include<boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include<boost/serialization/map.hpp>

//this is what i received from the server
size_t const len = m_socket.receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf), m_sender_endpoint);

    std::string const received_message(recv_buf.data(), len);

std::string archive_data(received_message);// receive from server
        std::istringstream archive_stream(archive_data);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
        archive >> map;
        displayCarData(map); //i'm passing this to function for printing the values
```

I tried with adding the Boost io binary library but then the error is :
    c++ out of range memory location
      //this is my try with using io binary  library

```
 std::string archive_data(received_message);
            std::istringstream archive_stream(archive_data);
            boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream, boost::io::binary);
            archive >> map;
            displayCarData(map);
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: This lacks a [mcve].  There are too many unknown types and variables here.  [Edit] your question to include enough code that we can compile it.

Comment: could it be that the serialized data exceeds packet size

Comment: I think that would be the possibilty @sehe But is there any way to set the size for it???

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Which variables you don't understand?

Comment: The class `input` used in `serializeData`, the class and type for `map` used in `archive_data`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm  this both are different files, one is for server and other for client.. so basically i'm parsing the data through UDP so at the and the received_message is simmilar for both side... so afterthat i'm doing the deserialization of that vector data.. so at that time if the data is more than 2 records its gives me the error that i mension above... so can you tell me how can i increse the size of serialized data...

Comment: The field size sets a theoretical limit of 65,535 bytes (8 byte header + 65,527 bytes of data) for a UDP datagram. However the actual limit for the data length, which is imposed by the underlying IPv4 protocol, is 65,507 bytes (65,535 − 8 byte UDP header − 20 byte IP header).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//this is what i received from the server
size_t const len = m_socket.receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf,1024), m_sender_endpoint);
```

i think you must give the size in

```
 boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf,1024), m_sender_endpoint);
```

in this line and also for the server side also.

Answer (score 1):

```
archive << vector;
```

suggests you indeed serialize a `std::vector`

```
archive >> map;
```

suggests  you deserialize a `std::map`

That won't work. And indeed it will likely be [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).